# how to actually install mediawiki and run with docker?

Tags: mediawiki, docker

I tried

[mediawiki docker](https://github.com/nickstenning/dockerfiles/tree/master/mediawiki)

it says:

> When first run, the container will not contain a LocalSettings.php

But i don't understand how to get this contained `LocalSettings.php` what do I type to get this file? and how to I replace it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docker images from [mediawiki docker](https://github.com/nickstenning/dockerfiles/tree/master/mediawiki) uses `Volumes` which is clearly given in the description on the page. In case of Docker images with volumes when you download the image you need to create a similar volume on your host too, because downloading a docker image doesn
t download the docker volume.

As it is stated on that page, you need to create a volume in the host and put that LocalSettings.php file and then create a container as:

```
docker stop $CONFIG_CONTAINER
docker run -v /data/wiki:/data -d nickstenning/mediawiki
```

Comment: But where do I get this LocalSettings.php file from?

Comment: @Jas I dont have much idea about mediawiki, I guess this http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:LocalSettings.php can help you.

Comment: so i need to mount ./LocalSettings.php, /data, /var/www/html/sites or /var/www/html? or all of the above? and does LocalSettings.php go into /data? or /var/www/html?

Answer (score 1):

1.- We need to obtain the name of the docker

```
docker ps
```

2.- Obtain a shell inside the docker container

```
docker exec -it <dockername> /bin/bash

/var/www/html# ls -l
total 1576
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000     168 Sep 24 22:22 CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000   19421 Nov  4  2019 COPYING
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000   13101 Sep 24 22:22 CREDITS
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000      95 Nov  4  2019 FAQ
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000 1151718 Sep 24 22:22 HISTORY
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000    3581 Sep 24 22:22 INSTALL
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000    1525 Sep 24 22:22 README.md
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000   84664 Sep 25 14:36 RELEASE-NOTES-1.35
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000     199 Nov  4  2019 SECURITY
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000   12142 Sep 24 22:22 UPGRADE
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000    4490 Sep 24 22:22 api.php
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000  156532 Sep 24 22:22 autoload.php
drwxr-xr-x  2 www-data www-data    4096 Sep 30 01:19 cache
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000    4719 Sep 24 22:22 composer.json
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000     102 Nov  4  2019 composer.local.json-sample
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root        4096 Sep 30 01:19 docs
drwxr-xr-x 30 www-data www-data    4096 Sep 30 01:19 extensions
drwxr-xr-x  1 www-data www-data    4096 Oct  1 10:47 images
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000    8245 Sep 24 22:22 img_auth.php
drwxr-xr-x 83 root     root        4096 Sep 30 01:19 includes
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000    1977 Sep 24 22:22 index.php
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000    1428 Sep 24 22:22 jsduck.json
drwxr-xr-x  6 root     root        4096 Sep 30 01:19 languages
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000    1951 Sep 24 22:22 load.php
drwxr-xr-x 14 root     root       12288 Sep 30 01:19 maintenance
drwxr-xr-x  4 root     root        4096 Sep 30 01:19 mw-config
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000    4610 Sep 24 22:22 opensearch_desc.php
drwxr-xr-x  5 root     root        4096 Sep 30 01:19 resources
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000     998 Sep 24 22:22 rest.php
drwxr-xr-x  5 www-data www-data    4096 Sep 30 01:19 skins
drwxr-xr-x 10 root     root        4096 Sep 30 01:19 tests
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000   23408 Sep 24 22:22 thumb.php
-rw-rw-r--  1     1000     1000    1439 Sep 24 22:22 thumb_handler.php
drwxr-xr-x 16 root     root        4096 Sep 30 01:19 vendor
root@e532ae3bb563:/var/www/html# cat > LocalSettings.php
```

3.- Create a file and copy the contents of LocalSettings.php inside the directory

```
cat > LocalSettings.php
```

(and paste with the terminal the contents of the downloaded LocalSettings, you can use some editor but using this command pasting the content and the ctrl+c should work).

Answer (score 0):

This is old, although I didn't have much success with copying in a previous `LocalSettings.php`. You just pass in the extra environment variables and a `LocalSettings.php` will be created in the data directory. Then you just put your custom changes in `conf/CustomSettings.php`

> Use the following environmental variables to generate a `LocalSettings.php`
>
> - `-e MEDIAWIKI_ADMIN_USER=` (defaults to `admin`; configures default administrator username)
> - `-e MEDIAWIKI_ADMIN_PASS=` (defaults to `rosebud`; configures default administrator password)

https://github.com/wikimedia/mediawiki-docker

I at least imported a previous database to get the posts visible, using the generated config and just adding my custom settings.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have completed the installation steps after you first initiated your container, you will be given a page with a `LocalSettings.php` file to download.

What worked for me was to download this file *inside* the container already, like the following:

1. Open a terminal inside the container (you can use Docker Desktop to do that by clicking on the CLI button in the container view OR run the command `docker exec -it <container name> /bin/sh`)
2. Inside the terminal, run the command: `curl http://0.0.0.0:80/mw-config/index.php?localsettings=1 > LocalSettings.php`

That's it! It will download de generated file into your root folder, which is where the terminal will open at start.